# NHibernate Many to Many "Other" column

Tags: nhibernate, architecture, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I currently have 4 tables.

Product, Category, SubCategory, ProductSubCategory.

Category has a OneToMany SubCategory relationship

Product has a OneToOne relationship with Category and a ZeroToMany relationship to SubCategory

So the tables look like this

**Product Table**

```
  Id     Name    CategoryId
-----------------------------
  1      P1      1
  2      P2      2
```

**Category Table**

```
  Id     Name
-----------------    
  1      Food    
  2      Travel
```

**SubCategory Table**

```
  Id     Name     CategoryId   
------------------------------
  1      Italian  1
  2      Thai     1
```

**ProductSubCategory Table**

```
  Id     ProductId     SubCategoryId     Other
-------------------------------------------------------   
  1      1             1                 NULL
  2      1             2                 NULL
  3      1             NULL              Other Sub Cat
```

Currently I have it ProductSubCategory in another class where Product and SubCategory have a OneToMany relationship to it.

**Product Class**

```
public class Product
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductSubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

**SubCategory Class**

```
public class SubCategory
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductSubCategory> Products { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

**ProductSubCategory Class**

```
public class ProductSubCategory
{
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual string Other { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

I would like to access it this way: "Product.SubCategories[x].Name" which would return the SubCategory Name or "Other" Name

Currently to get the Name I have to type out "Product.SubCategories[x].SubCategory.Name" and to get the "Other" Name I have to type "Product.SubCategories[x].Other"

Is there a better way of this?

Thanks!

EDIT: Fixed typo's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add projected properties to `ProductSubCategory` if you want to type less :-)

```
public virtual string Name
{
    get { return SubCategory.Name; }
}
```